# What's an antonym for the noun "critic"?

Tags: antonyms

I need an antonym (a noun) for the word "Critic", ie. a noun for someone who praises.

Answer (score 2):

Flatterer or sycophant come to mind.

> sycophant, n: servile, cringing, or abject flatterer; lickspittle.

But I should point out that *critic* can be a neutral term. Critics often praise.  Movie critics do like movies from time to time and often say so.

Answer (score 2):

First I would like to point out that a critic says both positive and negative things.  So the opposite viewpoint of a critic could be another ***critic***.

However if you take critic to mean someone who is negative towards a topic, then I would consider **advocate** as a good antonym.

> a person who publicly supports or recommends a particular cause or
>   policy.

Answer (score 0):

**Praiser**: [someone who expresses commendation, admiration, etc, for](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/praiser?showCookiePolicy=true)

**Proneur**:      [n. a person who extols; a flatterer.
    Etymology: F procircneur f. procircner eulogize f. procircne place in church where addresses were delivered](http://useful_english.enacademic.com/269478/proneur)

**Encomiast**: [Encomiast En*co"mi*ast, n. [Gr. ?, fr. ? to praise, fr. ? encomium: cf. F. encomiaste. See {Encomium}.] One who praises; a panegyrist. --Locke.](http://en.academic.ru/dic.nsf/cide/58353/Encomiast)

**panegyrist**: [a person who panegyrizes; eulogist.](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/panegyrist)

Answer (score 0):

More common antonyms might be fan, supporter, or devotee.

Answer (score 0):

I would say "[promoter](http://www.promodo.com/blog/nps-calculate-wisely-apply-the-results)."

> [promoter](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/promoter): a person or thing that promotes, furthers, or encourages.

Answer (score 0):

Supporter

OS X dictionary

**supporter** |səˈpôrtər| noun

**1** a person who approves of and encourages someone or something (typically a public figure, a movement or party, or a policy): Reagan supporters | supporters of the boycott.
• a person who is actively interested in and wishes success for a particular sports team.